# Need help nesting multiple formulas

Tags: google-sheets

I have three functions that will return the answer that I'm looking for but I don't want to have these functions separate because the sheet would get too cluttered. That said, I'm having difficulties nesting these formulas so that it returns only the final output. The formulas are listed below:

`=UNIQUE(FILTER('Sheet'!$D:$D, 'Sheet'!$B:$B >= B$2,'Sheet'!$B:$B<C$2,regexmatch('Sheet'!$L:$L,"Trial")))`
This function returns all unique ID's that meet the conditions stated.

`=COUNTIFS('Sheet'!$B:$B,">="&C$2,'Sheet'!$B:$B,"<"&D$2,'Sheet'!$G:$G,">0",'Sheet'!$D:$D,B27)>0`
This function returns T/F if the identified unique ID from first function exists next month. Returns 'True' if ID exists, 'False" if it does not. Cell B27 refers to the first cell row from the first function.

`=COUNTIF(C27:C45,TRUE)`
This function counts all True for each month. Range (C27:C45) references the output from the second function

I tried
`=COUNTIF(countifs('Sheet'!$B:$B,">="&C$2,'Sheet'!$B:$B,"<"&D$2,'Sheet'!$G:$G,">0",'Sheet'!$D:$D,UNIQUE(FILTER('Sheet'!$D:$D, 'Sheet'!$B:$B >= B$2,'Sheet'!$B:$B<C$2,regexmatch('Sheet'!$L:$L,"Trial"))))>0,TRUE)`
but this function returns the incorrect answer.

Any ideas? Here's the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l2dXCEE0enTRBzBZEwjN1Fj9-ovPjsi75WvTdgK7_Zg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: shared https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l2dXCEE0enTRBzBZEwjN1Fj9-ovPjsi75WvTdgK7_Zg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: your calculation is wrong. you getting count of 18 but it should be 17 because OrderID 1034 has 0 in the G column and OrderIDs 1098 and 1123 do not have Trial in L column

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(IFNA(FILTER(sheet!$D:$D, sheet!$B:$B >= B$2, sheet!$B:$B < C$2, 
 REGEXMATCH(sheet!$L:$L, "Trial"), sheet!$G:$G > 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Although this function works for column B, it is inaccurate for the rest of the months/columns as returned value should not exceed count from Function 1 (in this case, the calculated results cannot be greater than 19)

Comment: from what I understand, your function is counting the unique ID's in each month if they have a Trial plan. What I'm trying to do is to track the original ID's pulled from Function 1 throughout the calendar year to see if if they cancelled their plan or not.

Comment: @SangwooChun not rly sure what are you after... maybe this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH5NR.png ?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Had to use =arrayformula nested over the three functions.

Column B shows the number of new subscribers.
Column C:V shows how many of the specified subscribers from ColB is retained over period of time.

[image]